# SUMIFS using two unrelated Tables in Excel on same rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, excel-tables

When building a financial model that is set up using multiple unrelated tables, however on the same rows across the worksheet, I am having trouble with structuring formulas the same way as you would with a single Table in Excel.

The very first table is a summary table of different projects and columns with different characteristics of each project, and the subsequent tables for the same rows to the right are structured with months/years as table headers and financial information for each period. I am now trying to build formulas that summarize information in these tables by using SUMIFS formulas that take characteristics of the projects as criteria. Typically, this would look like:

=SUMIFS(BacklogTable[des.21],ProjectsTable[Segment],"Healthcare")

Under circumstances where all this data would be part of the same table, this would yield the result I am looking for. However, as these two tables are not connected in any way, the formula returns #VALUE.

I have noticed that referencing the same row of another Table works just fine. Standing in the cell of Table2 and referencing the same row of Table1 (Table1[@[Segment]]) returns the correct value from Table1.

Is there a way to modify the formula such that Excel can interpret criterias that stretch across an entire Table column and match it with the corresponding same rows of a different Table?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BaHG.png)

Data Relationships in Excel does not seem like a solution. The problem can of course be resolved by adding the same information in the summary table to every other table, but for future projects it would be nice to know if using multiple tables can be a way to structure large models.

Comment: `SUMIFS()` doesn't care about whether tables are related; it cares about ranges being the same size so e.g. if `BacklogTable[des.21]` doesn't have exactly the same number of cells as `ProjectsTable[Segment]` then that will explain your `#VALUE` error

Comment: That was indeed the problem here. I was sure the ranges were of the same size, but just realized that one of the tables had one less row. Changing them to the exactly same size solved the problem. Many thanks!